# How can I execute hbase shell on mini hbase cluster?

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I'm going to do integration tests and to do this I starts MiniHbaseCluster (http://hbase.apache.org/). How can I run hbase shell script on it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write use same bash scripting EOF as per the below example

```
#!/bin/sh
hbase shell <<EOF 
scan 'mytable',{LIMIT => 10}
exit
EOF
```